# Selecting elements from a particular component which is rendered mulitple times in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have a component `card` which is rendered multiple times,each containing different data, like so:

```
{ this.state.response.reminders.map((item,i=0) =>{
                                return <Card key={i++} reminder={item} deleteRem={this.deleteReminder}/>
                            }
                        )}
```

The `card` component has a button which when clicked deletes the card. I do this by extracting data from that particular `card` in which the button is clicked, post it to my flask backend to delete from the database. The problem lies in the way I am extracting data, by accessing each element like so:

```
let plainData = {};
plainData['reminder']=event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[1].children[0].children[0].value
plainData['date']= event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[0].innerText
```

The huge chain of selection statement is a really bad piece of code, I know it. This was a quick and dirty way I adopted to get it working. But I am curious as to how this can be **properly** done. Thanks for reading!

#### Edit:

I think my question was not properly delivered. Precisely, I am concerned with the long and untidy code:
`plainData['reminder']=event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].children[1].children[0].children[0].value`
What is a better way of selecting the elements ?

Comment: Small note: No need for the `i++`, since the resulting `i+1` isn't immediatly used and `i` gets reset next "iteration" anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass a small arrow function which directly passes `item` to `deleteReminder`:

```js
this.state.response.reminders.map((item, i) => {
    return <Card key={i} reminder={item} deleteRem={() => this.deleteReminder(item)} />
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use react hook with functional components, Based on your code i can see you are using Class Based components `this.` gives that away.

So i will explain for the both;

1. Functional Components with hooks

you can use useEffect hook and its dependency array, which you can get the rerenders whenever those dependencies in the use effects array changes

```
useEffect(() => {
       someFunction()
     ,[dependency, someOtherDependency]}
```

component rerender only when `dependency` or `someOtherDependency`  changes

2. Class Components

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if (this.props !== prevProps) {
   doSomethingFunc()
} 

// I can also check specific prop as well

if (this.props.someSpecificProp !== prevProps.someSpecificProp) {
   doSomethingFunc()
}
}
```

Comment: This is good advice, but doesn't answer the question. Should probably be a comment.